# Can an encryption key be inferred by knowing the plaintext and the corresponding ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, aes

Thinking about validation methods for guaranteeing a proper key is used. Will keeping a dummy plaintext value and its corresponding ciphertext in plaintext code expose any risk?

Comment: Key-recovery resistance is a basic requirement in all modern ciphers under the assumption that any practical number of plaintext-ciphertext pair are known by the adversary.

Comment: The title a bit confusing, are you simply asking is there a secure way to see that the key is correct before decryption and validation of the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thinking!

The good news is that, when you use authenticated encryption, there's no need to keep such "dummy" plaintext-ciphertext pair.

In a typical authenticated encryption, a tag is computed based on the key, the plaintext, and possibly additional data (e.g. AAD, Initialization Vector), so that upon decryption, the tag is verified for correctness. Typically, the tag is 128-bit as is the case with GCM-AES and ChaCha20-Poly1305.

Successful decryption of an authenticated ciphertext indicates that if the correct key had been used then the ciphertext along with other inputs to the encryption algorithm are correct and had not be modified by any man-in-the-middle.

Comment: What if the file is too long to see that? The proper way is to use the first block as identification and this is still secure since we need at least Ind-CPA secure ciphers.

Comment: @kelalaka You make a good point. For large files, reserving an initial segment of data for key verification using some kind of key derivation function can speed it up a bit. We'll see what OP's use case is and then determine if more details deserve to be added.

Comment: "Successful decryption of an authenticated ciphertext indicates that both the correct key had been used" is not correct for AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305. Neither is key-committing, so multiple keys may decrypt to different plaintexts but still have the same tag. If you need key committment, that's easy to add, just stick a hash of the key in the AAD and validate it during decryption.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus Updated for the fact.

Comment: FYI: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/016.pdf is the paper that AFAIK first showed a case where the lack of key commitment caused undesired behavior. https://keymaterial.net/2020/09/07/invisible-salamanders-in-aes-gcm-siv/ is an easy-to-understand writeup (though if you are actually "Danny" Niu Jianfang you probably don't need the blog post).